tzwhere returns empty even with forceTZ enabled
I am using tzwhere module to get the timezone based on coordinates. I recently found I can set forceTZ=True but when I do this, it still does not return a timezone.
My code is:
from tzwhere import tzwhere
tz = tzwhere.tzwhere(forceTZ=True)
tz.tzNameAt(18.45903590,-67.16367790)

However this still returns None. Am I doing something wrong?

if I run your code on Python 3.12.1 / tzwhere 3.0.3, it errors with a ValueError (setting array element with sequence)... I'm with @GabrielTkacz here, I'd also recommend using timezonefinder instead. Development seems to be active and it's much more performant in my experience.

Which Python version are you using? AFAIK tzwhere hasn't been ported to Python 3. An analogous code for Python 3 would be:
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder 

tz = TimezoneFinder()
tz.timezone_at(lat=18.45903590, lng=-67.16367790)


tzwhere V3.0.3 is compatible with Python3

It's still from 2017, I really wouldn't recommend using it. Is there a reason you can't use another lib like timezonefinder?
